# React Higher Order Component With Redux causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, higher-order-components

I'm trying to show loading while data is fetching from API and I want a higher-order component to achieve this. But my code causes an infinite loop

```
 //home.tsx file
export class Home extends Component<Props, any> {
  componentDidMount(): void {
    this.props.getCharacters();
  }

  render() { 
    return (
    <div></div>
   )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState): StateProps => {
  return {
    loading:state.marvel.loading,
    data: getResultsSelector(state),
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps: DispatchProps = {
  getCharacters,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WithLoading(Home));

 //hoc.tsx file
function WithLoading(Component:any) {
  return function WihLoadingComponent({ loading, ...props }:any) {

    console.log(loading)
    if (!loading) return <Component {...props} />;
    return <p>Hold on, fetching data might take some time.</p>;
  };
}
export default WithLoading;
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `getCharacters()` is the function that fetches data from the API.

The Component is mounted depending on `loading`, but `loading` is set when the Component is mounted.

1. `if (!loading) return <Component />;` mounts the component.
2. `componentDidMount` invokes `getCharacters()`
3. `getCharacters()` sets `loading = true`
4. `if (!loading) return <Component />;` does **not** return the Component anymore.
5. when loading is done: `loading = false`
6. `if (!loading) return <Component />;` mounts the component **again**.
7. continue at 2.

The loading and mounting must be made independent of each other.

- **A.** Either you should not invoke the loading inside the Component,
- **B.** or you should not mount the Component conditionally.

#### A: separate the loading from the Component

As you probably want to create a generic HOC that shows some arbitrary Component only when `loaded === true`, you might prefer A., which means you have to design the Components so that they do not change `loading` themselves.

There might be ways to do that, e.g.:

```
componentDidMount(): void {
    if( !this.props.dataHasAlreadyBeFetched ){
        this.props.getCharacters();
    }
}
```

but I think that would be bad style, and it seems to me that in your case it makes sense to separate it, because apparently the only reason your Component is mounted the first time is to invoke `getCharacters`, which unmounts the Component.

#### B: not un-mount the Component

The Component is always mounted (without `if( !loading)`), and itself has to be designed to render any content only if `loading === true` (and otherwise `null`). Of course, `loading` has to be passed to the Component as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't get the point. Can you give me a code example?

Comment: just do not call `getCharacters()` inside the Component, but call it somewhere outside your `WithLoading` HOC.

Comment: Then how can i get the data. Sorry I can't fully comprehend. İ will appreciate if you provide code example in your answer

Comment: I added an example for (B). For (A) maybe call `getCharacters()` inside the `componentDidMount()` of the parent component. But I don't know what exactly you want to achieve. The code that you posted can not be changed to work like I would recommend. Maybe exactly what you want is not possible. Also I guess it would be outside the scope of this question. You may ask another question on what you do not understand. Maybe see also [componentdidmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Comment: I want to show loading screen while data is fetching and I want to achieve this with loading hoc. That is exactly I want.